# add a column under a condition in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my model

```
class User_quiz_logs(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    user_quiz_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    response = models.CharField('response ', max_length=300, null=False)
    points = models.IntegerField('points', null=True)
    state_quiz = models.BooleanField('state', default=False)
```

has an attribute points that I want to add if it corresponds to the same person?

Example

```
1   A   1   true    141
2   A   1   true    141
3   A   1   true    141
4   B   5   true    165
5   C   1   true    165
```

The person with id 141 the total sum of his points would be 3 and id 165 would be 6 total points.

Comment: "tiene un atributo puntos que quiero sumar si corresponde a un mismo persona"?

Comment: if that is the purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

User.objects.annotate(
    points=Sum('user_quiz_logs__points', filter=Q(user_quiz_logs__state_quiz=True))
)
```

The `User` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.points` that will contain the total sum of the `points` of the related `user_quiz_logs` for that `User`.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`User_quiz_logs`</s> to `UserQuiz`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `user`, instead of <s>`user_id`</s>.